# Use a CSV file to populate a webpage that display the latest weather using flask?

Tags: python, csv, flask, html, output

I am using JSON to take some weather data and output this data on a CSV file like this.

[image]

I would like to know how to display my CSV file in a web browser using Flask (already installed)? Here is my code so far (its working)

```
#Source : http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples
import urllib2
import json
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime#set the time
from flask import Flask, send_file
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

def get_information(url):
  try:
    wunder_url_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  except:
    print 'Could not open URL'
    return None

  else:
    now = datetime.now()
    current_year = now.year
    current_day = now.day
    current_month = now.month
    current_hour = now.hour
    current_minute = now.minute
    current_second = now.second
    json_string = wunder_url_obj.read()
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
    temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
    weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather']
    date = str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.year) + " " +         str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)
    now = datetime.now()    
    header = "Datetime,current condition,Temperature,\n" 

    with open('out.csv', 'a+') as f:
      f.seek(0, 2) # os.SEEK_END, on Windows file position set to 0 even in append mode.
      if f.tell() == 0:
        f.write(header)
      f.write(','.join([date, str(temp_f), weather]))
      f.write('\n')
      f.close()

get_information('http://api.wunderground.com/api/8d3b5d3fa03ddb6f/conditions/weather/q/China/Beijing.json')

@app.route("/weather.csv")
def weather():
    url =     'http://api.wunderground.com/api/8d3b5d3fa03ddb6f/conditions/weather/q/China/Beijing.json'
    get_information(url)
    return send_file("out.csv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here a screenshot of my Editor :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [send_file()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_file). The flask endpoint would look something like:

```
from flask import Flask, send_file
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

# Your get_information method

@app.route("/weather.csv")
def weather():
    url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/8d3b5d3fa03ddb6f/conditions/weather/q/China/Beijing.json"
    get_information(url)
    return send_file("out.csv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: How can i do that on my code to work properly ? sorry newby start python 2 months ago) i try to stuff for the first time.

Comment: What part isn't working properly? If you've never used Flask before, start with the [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) guide.

Comment: I never use Flask before,will follow the Quickstart and come back here if i got questions

Comment: don't have successfull set the Flask,god why i cant understand this !

Comment: Start simple. Can you get the Hello World example (from the top of the Quickstart) to run? If you can do that, you can add your method and mine below the 'Hello World!'.

Comment: yeah i set this on a new .py file,work good. it run the server,and when i go to the server it's appear good,"Hello World",i will try now to run my method and your below.Thanks for Helping a New guy in programming Cat.

Comment: I edit my code with putting Flask on it Cat,nothing appear under the "Hello World" can you explain to me what's wrong ? Did i set the stuff wrong ?

Comment: @Nardrek Okay, there's quite a few mistakes there that will trip you up:

Comment: @Nardrek Okay, there's a few mistakes there that will trip you up: first, you need to [watch your indenting](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html) (tabs or spaces). Then when you set the url, you have quotation marks " in the wrong place. You need one each side of the url. I've also edited my answer to fix a typo :(.

Comment: Thanks cat for the infos,got just a URL issue,like The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. i will edit my code and post a screenshot of my editor,i change the indentation correctly(important),please reload the page i changes my Edit.thanks for the help,very apreciate this,

Comment: any idea why have a URL problem ?

Comment: @Nardrek The url set is  http://localhost:5000/weather.csv which works fine for me. If you want it to be different, change the "/weather.csv" to be the relative path you would like (e.g. just "/" or "/myfile.csv")

Comment: interesting ,in fact the http://localhost:5000/weather.csv just in fact download the file from the server( that's nice) but don't display my info on on Webpage like i wanted,i want my file been display on a html page.this is cool too.